# Observer method in MVVM Design Pattern swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm, observer-pattern

I have one question about the code you can see below.

```
class Bindable<T> {
    var value: T? {
        didSet {
            observer?(value)
        }
    }

    var observer: ((T?) -> ())?

    func bind(observer: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {
        self.observer = observer // there is the place ı can not understand
        observer?(value)
    }
}
```

Why we doing this `self.observer = observer`? I expect we should use `observer = self.observer` instead of `self.observer = observer`. The reason why I think just like that
that is I think

1. We have changed the value
2. `self.observer` will worked
3. When we called `func bind()` because of the parameter `observer` is going to be equal to `self.observer` everything needs to be work perfectly.

But, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand any of points 1-3, but I can say for sure that while `self.observer = observer` makes sense to me, `observer = self.observer` does not and would certainly not compile, as the `observer` sent in via a parameter is not mutable.

Comment: why self.observer = observer is makes sense to you plz explain me more deeply plz @jnpdx

Comment: Because you have a `var observer` property on your class. You're setting that equal to the `observer` parameter that's passed into `bind`.

Comment: that is the what ı can not understand how can class property pass into bind method @jnpdx

Comment: I don't know what that means. Perhaps you're getting confused because both the class property and the parameter are named `observer` -- maybe if you renamed one of them it would make it more clear what is happening here.

Comment: you have discord or some platform can we talk @jnpdx

Comment: No, but I'm happy to answer questions here if I can when I have time. Also, if you keep the discussion here, others benefit from being able to answer or see the answers as well.

Comment: ok ı will prepare ordered document for my problem ok? @jnpdx so ı can explain myself more clearly

Comment: https://medium.com/cubo-ai/implementing-mvvm-binding-with-generics-in-swift-d5cf895e9eb8 here is the link for document @jnpdx

Comment: Unfortunately, for me, that doesn't clarify what the confusion is. Perhaps someone else will have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

`self.observer = observer` means you assign this function to the class property `observer`

The first `self.observer` is the observer you defined in `var observer: ((T?) -> ())?`

And the second `observer` is the one you passed through the function `func bind(observer: @escaping (T?) -> ())`

Give you another example you will understand better.

```swift
class Person {
    var age: Int = 0

    func setAge(age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }

    // to let you understand better
    // if the param is `anotherAge`
    // `self.` is not necessary
    func setAge2(anotherAge: Int) {
        age = anotherAge
    }
}
```

The `self.age = age` here is nothing different from your `self.observer = observer`, all are assigned a value to a class property.
The only difference is that your `observer` is a function also.

Comment: Okey but why did we assign age = anotherage @Heaven

Comment: @Sait47 `anotherAge` is just a param name. The func here is to set the value of age. Depends on your purpose. E.g. if `age` in `Person` is private like `private var age: Int = 0`, you can not set the value to it directly, then you might need a setter like `func setAge(age: Int)`, for your function `bind`, it has more functionality. Not only set the  `observer` also pass value and call the `observer function`

Comment: okey ı could undertstand that part but taht is the point ı have been stucking, how can class observer closure is work when ı called bind function @Heaven

Comment: also what is the benefit of self.observer = observer @Heaven

Comment: @Sait47 When you call `bind`, it just init the `observer` in your class. The key point of `Bindable` is after you init the `observer`, inside `value`'s `didSet`, every time your value is set, the `observer?(value)` will be called, which observe the change of your value

Comment: @Sait47 Did I explain clearly?